# Read/Write specific key inside plist - iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad, plist

I have a simple question.
Let's say I have a pList that contains 1 string and 2 arrays. Each Array has 100 elements.
Is there a way to load only 1 of the 2 arrays without loading the entire pList into memory ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plist is a XML format text file. So, you can parse the file by XML parser with `SAX` manner. The sample code [XMLPerformance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008094) includes a good example about `libxml` which parses data with `SAX` manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought Apple included a specific function to do that. Anyway, that's exactly what I was looking for.